# Nagios PostgreSQL security concern

Tags: postgresql, nagios

I have just setup nagios and one of the services I'm monitoring is postgresql. In order to make it work I have created a user `nagios` on the hosts with a password.

Opened up port `5432` on the firewall and configured pg_hba.conf with:

```
host    template1    nagios   0.0.0.0/0    password
```

Is this the correct way to set it up? I am concerned about security being the database exposed to the internet.

Comment: Why would you do this instead of opening it up to only the IP of your nagios server?

Comment: Damn....... how silly am I.. Too much time spent configuring and didn't even think about it... Thanks. Want to answer and I'll accept...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right to question the security ramifications of this. So don't do it. Allow connections only from your nagios server. Additionally, create firewall rules that restrict connections from only where you need them to come from.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not monitoring the availability of Postgres over the network, there's no need to check it over the network socket.

Meaning, if it's only used from localhost, you can just run your check via NRPE, ssh + keys, etc.

Comment: Thanks but I am actually monitoring over network.